# Transaction Laravel schema create

Tags: database, laravel, transactions

I'm trying to create a transaction when I use the  Schema::create method but it doesn't work.In my application I have to create dynamic table on a different DB and in case of error I have to rollback. Laravel launches exception but the rollback doesn't work. I'm using laravel 5.1

Comment: Try to run composer dumpauto and then rollback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using MySQL. DDL statements (create table, alter table, etc) cannot be rolled back in transactions.

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html):

> Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include data definition language (DDL) statements, such as those that create or drop databases, those that create, drop, or alter tables or stored routines.
>
> You should design your transactions not to include such statements. If you issue a statement early in a transaction that cannot be rolled back, and then another statement later fails, the full effect of the transaction cannot be rolled back in such cases by issuing a ROLLBACK statement.